# Python string formatting, include the 0 at the end

Tags: python, function, numpy, string-formatting

I am using Python's string formatting method inside a definition to call some .txt files. One such example is:

```
def call_files(zcos1,zcos1,sig0):
    a,b = np.loadtxt('/home/xi_'+str(zcos1)+'<zphot'+str(sig0)+'<'+str(zcos2)+'_.dat',unpack=True)
```

Here `str(sig0)` is given the call where `sig0 == 0.050`. However when I do so, instead of taking `0.050`, it is rounded off to `0.05` !

**How do I make `str(sig0)` to be `0.050` instead of `0.05` ?**

Comment: It's not [string formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) or `%` :

```
>>> "{:.03f}".format(0.05)
'0.050'
```

You could format the whole path with a single call to `str.format()` like this:

```
a, b = np.loadtxt("/home/xi_{}<zphot{:.03f}<{}_.dat".format(zcos1, sig0, zcos2),
                  unpack=True)
```

or using keyword arguments as [Adam Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34709173/python-string-formatting-include-the-0-at-the-end/34709214#comment57164530_34709214) suggested below:

```
a, b = np.loadtxt("/home/xi_{cos1}<zphot{sig0:.03f}<{cos2}_dat".format(
    cos1=zcos1, sig0=sig0, cos2=zcos2), unpack=True)
```

Comment: agreed that string formatting is the way to go here. `np.loadtxt("/home/xi_{cos1}<zphot{sig0:.03f}<{cos2}_dat".format(cos1=zcos1, sig0=sig0, cos2=zcos2), unpack=True)

Comment: @eugene y: can you please explain further, i.e. as to how I exactly use it in my situation